# Asymptotic solution of an integro-differential equation

Tags: asymptotics, levy-processes, integro-differential-equations

Motivated by a problem of Lévy-flights in a potential, I am looking for the asymptotics of a function $f(y)$, which obeys the the integro-differential equation
$$ e^{2y} f(y) = C \frac{d}{dy}\int_y^\infty \frac{f(z)}{(z-y)^{\alpha-1}} dy,$$
with a constant $C$, and $\alpha\in(1,2)$ in the limit $y\to \infty$. I know from numerical solutions that it decays faster than exponentially, but I struggled to get an analytical expression.

**EDIT:** I am assuming $f$ to be positive (it is a probability density in the original problem) and it decays to zero at infinity faster than exponentially.

Comment: Does it decay to zero?

Comment: Also, are there any assumptions on $f$? For instance, if it's positive, that could help.

Comment: Yes, $f(y)$ decays to zero, and it is positive. For the analogous question for the case where the left-hand side is $\mu f(y)$  instead of $e^{2y} f(y)$, with another constant $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, and with the integral being $\int_{-\infty}^y$ instead of $\int_y^\infty$, which arises in the same context, I now found the answer. One simply uses an exponential ansatz $f(z)=\exp(az)$ and pulls $\exp(ay)$ out of the integral and changes integration variable to $u=z-y$. This leads to an expression for $a\propto \mu^{1/(\alpha-1)}$. However, this approach trick does not seem to work here anymore...

Comment: I am suspecting that what I'm asking is impossible to do, since the integro-differential term is the integral of the order $\alpha$ left Weyl fractional derivative, which has no simple exact expression when applied to most nontrivial functions really according to my literature search at least ...